# Deleting icloud.com mail account from single user on multiple user computer

Tags: email

Our iMac is set up for four different users. For  some reason my icloud.com mail account has appeared on my daughters side of the computer. If I delete this from her side will I delete it on my side( and consequently on my iPad and iphone)? Or can I simply delete my mail account from her mail programme.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete an iCloud account from OS X system preferences, nothing changes on Apple's server side. No data is lost, just your local copy is removed and the syncing stops.

- Sign out in one or all accounts
- Sign back in on the Mac account where you want to use iCloud

No matter what I say, a Time Machine backup before starting any change is always a good thing, just in I wasn't clear to you or something goes wrong or I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that would be the case! I'll give it a go!